# Firebase iOS 14 support

Tags: ios, firebase

Is There any information about minimum **Firebase version** for iOS 14 ?

I already try to find but not yet found. thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, iOS Apps and Firebase SDKs continue to work for future versions of the operating system.

If you're interested in specific Firebase support for a particular new iOS 14 feature, support varies across the various Firebase libraries and across versions.

See the [Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) for details.